# A step in the proof of Sobolev embedding theorem

Tags: inequality, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

I am reading the proof of the Sobolev embedding theorem in Brezis' book, but i can't understand the following fact.

Suppose we've already proved the following lemma:

Let $f_1$, $f_2$, $\dots$, $f_N \in L^{N-1}(\mathbb{R}^{N-1})$ and set $$\tilde{x_i}=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\dots,x_N) \in \mathbb{R}^{N-1}.$$ 
Then the function $$ f(x)=f_1(\tilde{x_1})\dots f_N(\tilde{x_N}), \quad x \in\mathbb{R}^N$$ 
is in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $$||f||_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^N)} \leq \prod_{i=1}^{N}||f_i||_{L^{N-1}(\mathbb{R}^{N-1})}.$$

Now, in the theorem, one considers $u\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and 
$$
f_i(\tilde{x_i}):= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\bigg|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{i-1},t,x_{i+1},\dots,x_N)\bigg|dt
$$
so that 
$$
|u(x)|^N \leq \prod_{i} f_i(\tilde{x_i})
$$
and then one should be able (by using the previous lemma) - and this is the point I am missing - to prove that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |u(x)|^{\frac{N}{N-1}}dx \leq \prod_{i} ||f_i||^\frac{1}{N-1}_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^{N-1})}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raise both sides of your penultimate inequality to the power $1/(N-1)$ and integrate to get 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |u(x)|^{N/(N-1)}dx \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \prod_{i} f_i^{1/(N-1)}.
$$
Now apply your lemma to 
$$
g = \prod_{i} f_i^{1/(N-1)}
$$
with $g_i = f_i^{1/(N-1)}$.  This gives
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \prod_{i} f_i^{1/(N-1)} = \Vert g \Vert_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)} \le \prod_{i=1}^N \Vert g_i \Vert_{L^{N-1}(\mathbb{R}^{N-1})} = \prod_{i=1}^N \Vert f_i \Vert_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{N-1})}^{1/(N-1)}.
$$
Hence 
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |u(x)|^{N/(N-1)} dx\le \prod_{i=1}^N \Vert f_i \Vert_{L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{N-1})}^{1/(N-1)},
$$ 
which is what you were after.